# copying same data and creating nested dict,as per the different values in keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, nested

**I have this input as a config file**

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
dat = 4,5
```

**I am trying to create a nested dict(d1{}) in format as below from above input:**

```
{
    "0": {
        "a ": "1",
        "b ": "2",
        "c": "3",
        "dat": "4"
    },
    "1": {
        "a ": "1",
        "b ": "2",
        "c": "3",
        "dat": "5"
    }
}
```

**Below is python code i am using,**

```
import json
data_file = "Dataset" # as above input data from a file
d = {}
d1 = {}
with open(data_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.strip().split('=')
        d[key] = val
    l1 =  d['dat']
    z = l1.strip(' ').split(',')
d.pop('dat')

d1['0'] = d
d1['1'] = d

d1['0']['dat']= z[0]
d1['1']['dat']= z[1]
print d1
```

**And this is the output/result i am getting as below instead of what i am expecting as given above**

```
{
    "0": {
        "a ": "1",
        "b ": "2",
        "c": "3",
        "dat": "5"
    },
    "1": {
        "a ": "1",
        "b ": "2",
        "c": "3",
        "dat": "5"
    }
}
```

**As you can see above i am unable to store different values in 'dat' key of both 'datasets' 0 & 1 of nested dict and it appears to be same even after assigning different values of list index z[0] & z[1].
Can somebody let me know what wrong am i doing in above code, so as the value gets updated in both datasets are different.**

Comment: In lines `d1['0'] = d
 and d1['1'] = d`
You are literally saving the same value in both.

Comment: @code_byter : yes that is what i want to create nested dict with same datasets, please see my expected output above. also let me know if there is a better way to do it!

Comment: @shivrk you didn't understand @code_byter's answer. `d1['0']` and `d1['1']` are not **identical** dictionaries, they are **the same** dictionary - if you change `d1['0']['dat']` it is the same as if you changed `d1['1']['dat']`.

Comment: Your problem requirements are not clear. Are you sure you will get only one line in the file with multiple values, and will that definitely be the last line in the file?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: No it can be any line (but is in my control so will keep it last for now), i have posted a sample only here. I just want to create identical datasets,which would have only one value changed in form of nested dicts.

Comment: So you are sure that you will get exactly one line in the file with multiple values, but it may be any line?

Comment: @Błotosmętek: just tried this as per your reply **if you change d1['0']['dat'] it is the same as if you changed d1['1']['dat']**  but i think its not same, Tried this 
`z = ['dsfj','ashj'] 
d1 = {
    "0": {
        "a ": "1",
        "b ": "2",
        "c": "3",
        "dat": "4"
    },
    "1": {
        "a ": "1",
        "b ": "2",
        "c": "3",
        "dat": "5"
    }
}

d1['0']['dat'] = z[0]
d1['1']['dat'] = z[1]
print d1['0']['dat']
print d1['1']['dat']
print d1`

Comment: @RoryDaulton : Yes Rory as it is a input config file, but surely atleast one  line will have multiple values (working on a solution which will have lines with more mutiple values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that python never makes copies of objects implicitly.
When you do

```
d1['0'] = d
d1['1'] = d
```

d1['0'] and d1['1'] become references to d.

So d, d1['0'] and d1['1'] refer to the same objects.

And so when you change d, d1['0'] and d1['1'] get changed. Also when you change either of d1['0'] and d1['1'], the other one gets changed too.

For actually creating copies of dictionaries, you can either use dict.copy method:

```
d1['0'] = d.copy()
d1['1'] = d.copy()
```

or you can use dict() constructor:

```
d1['0'] = dict(d)
d1['1'] = dict(d)
```

Comment: Thank u! this solved the issue, also with explanation and example makes it more clear !!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Parse text file to several json configurations (with implicit configuration).

**file.txt**:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
dat = 4,5
```

Do:

```
import json

data_file = "file.txt"  # as above input data from a file
d = dict()
n_configs = 0
with open(data_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        key, values = [x.strip() for x in line.split('=')]
        values = [x.strip() for x in values.split(',')]
        if len(values) > n_configs:
            n_configs = len(values)
        d[key] = values

configs = dict()
for key, values in d.items():
    for n_config, value in enumerate(values):
        if n_config not in configs:
            configs[n_config] = dict()
        configs[n_config][key] = value
    n_config, value = len(values), values[-1]
    for n_missing_config in range(n_config, n_configs):
        if n_missing_config not in configs:
            configs[n_missing_config] = dict()
        configs[n_missing_config][key] = value

print(json.dumps(configs, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "0": {
        "a": "1",
        "c": "3",
        "b": "2",
        "dat": "4"
    },
    "1": {
        "a": "1",
        "c": "3",
        "b": "2",
        "dat": "5"
    }
}
```

This solution is more general, the last config for the given parameter will be the config for the next configs (if missing). See :

**file.txt**:

```
a = 1,4
b = 2,3
c = 3,6,7
dat = 4
```

Output:

```
{
    "0": {
        "a": "1",
        "c": "3",
        "b": "2",
        "dat": "4"
    },
    "1": {
        "a": "4",
        "c": "6",
        "b": "3",
        "dat": "4"
    },
    "2": {
        "a": "4",
        "c": "7",
        "b": "3",
        "dat": "4"
    }
}
```